# Adding function to sys.excepthook

Tags: python, coding-style, exception

Say I have something like this, which sends unhanded exceptions to `logging.critical()`:

```
import sys

def register_handler():
    orig_excepthook = sys.excepthook

    def error_catcher(*exc_info):
        import logging
        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        log.critical("Unhandled exception", exc_info=exc_info)
        orig_excepthook(*exc_info)

    sys.excepthook = error_catcher
```

It works:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

register_handler()

undefined() # logs, then runs original excepthook
```

However if `register_handler()` is called multiple times, multiple `error_catcher`'s are called in a chain, and the logging message appears several times..

I can think of a few ways, but none of them are particularly good (like checking if `sys.excepthook` is the error_catcher function, or using a "have_registered" attribute on the module to avoid double-registering)

Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a module-level "have the hook already been registered" variable seems like the simplest and most reliable way of doing this.

The other possible solutions would fall over in certain (rather obscure) circumstances - 
checking if the `sys.excepthook` is a builtin function will fail if an application registers a custom `excepthook`, storing the original `excepthook` at function-definition time will clobber subsequently registered excepthook functions.

```
import sys

_hook_registered = False

def register_handler(force = False):
    global _hook_registered

    if _hook_registered and not force:
        return

    orig_excepthook = sys.excepthook

    def error_catcher(*exc_info):
        import logging
        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        log.critical("Unhandled exception", exc_info=exc_info)
        orig_excepthook(*exc_info)

    sys.excepthook = error_catcher

    _hook_registered = True
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just check if `sys.excepthook` is still built-in function before registering your handler:

```
>>> import sys, types
>>> isinstance(sys.excepthook, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
True
>>> sys.excepthook = lambda x: x
>>> isinstance(sys.excepthook, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
False
```

Answer (score 3):

If you put the code in your question into a module, you can import it many times, but it will be executed only the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If you make `orig_excepthook` an argument with a default value, the default value is fixed once at definition-time. So repeated calls to `register_handler` will not change `orig_excepthook`.

```
import sys

def register_handler(orig_excepthook=sys.excepthook):
    def error_catcher(*exc_info):
        import logging
        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        log.critical("Unhandled exception", exc_info=exc_info)
        orig_excepthook(*exc_info)
    sys.excepthook = error_catcher
```

---

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

register_handler()
register_handler()
register_handler()

undefined()
```

produces only one call to `log.critical`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sys.__excepthook__`[1].
It is an object that contains the original values of `sys.excepthook`[2] at the start of the program.
ie;

```
import sys
import logging

def register_handler():
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    def error_catcher(*exc_info):
        log.critical("Unhandled exception", exc_info=exc_info)
        sys.__excepthook__(*exc_info)

    sys.excepthook = error_catcher
```

**Reference:**
1. [https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.**excepthook**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__excepthook__)
2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook