# How can I create block-scoped variables in Python?

Tags: python, scope

Take the following Perl code:

```
$a = 5;

if($a == 5)
{
    print $a;
    my $a = 8;
    print $a;
}

print $a;
```

This outputs `585` because `my $a` creates a new lexical variable that is scoped to the `if` block.

I want to do the same thing in Python, but this:

```
a = 5
b = 9

if a == 5:        
    print("inside function", b)
    b = 'apple'

print(b)
```

outputs

```
inside function 9
apple
```

The variable `b` is overwritten inside the `if`. Is there any way to create a local variable `b` inside the `if` statement? I want to use the same variable name with local scope inside the `if`.

Comment: Python `if` blocks are in the same scope as their surroundings. If you want a new scope, extract and call a function.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe  for quick reply. but we cant use function every time insted of if rite? no explicit way to make it local like "my" or "local" vars in other langages?

Comment: What? In general, you don't *need* a separate scope inside the `if`, but **if you do** you can create a new scope with a function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes..I agree,.we dont need a seperate scope inside if.  but in a rare condition where a user want to use a temporary variable inside the if block and need to name the temp var  to same variable which is already used outside.. in this case since the namespace is global, he cant use the same var inside py. No option in this case apart from using a subroutine ?  do he need to compormise in naming in if block ..Sorry if i didnt understood your previous explanation properly..

Comment: Yes, either use a different name or a different scope. How you do that is up to you. But an if block is not a separate scope.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for detailed replay.  Very very helpful for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temporarily changing a variable's value in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597692/temporarily-changing-a-variables-value-in-python)

Comment: In Python, the use of the semicolon as statement delimiter is unnecessary (one statement per line) and strongly discouraged (multiple statements per line):

https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations

And since Python 3 (where this issue still exists), ```print``` is a function.

I have edited the question accordingly. Thank you for it, though, as I just stumbled upon the same problem (I have been using Python for 14 years now, and for some reason thought it to be block-scoped).

Answer (score 2):

The codes are not equivalent; in the Perl code, the `my` inside the `if` block creates an entirely new variable, which goes out of scope when the containing block ends.

You can do something similar with a context manager in Python, but the syntax will be much different.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
a = 5
b = 9

def my_func(a):
    if a == 5:        
        b = 'apple'
        print("inside function: ", b)

my_func(a)
print("outside function: ", b)

> inside function: apple
> outside function: 9
```

`b` is a local variable inside the function `my_func` that is equal to `apple`, without affecting the global variable `b` that is equal to `9`.